# Python3.5.5 installed but not opening in Oracle Linux 6.9

Tags: python-3.x, linux, installation, pyinstaller, centos6

I have created a VM by installing Oracle Linux6.9 in Virtualbox. It comes default with Python2.6.

I have to install python 3.5 in it. I followed the instruction from https://www.looklinux.com/how-to-install-python-3-5-on-centosrhel-67/.
Also, while configuring I made the following enables:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --prefix=/opt/python LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/opt/python/lib
```

Reference for this : https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2131

Now, I'm not able to open python3. I've tried python3, python3.5, python35 inside `/opt/python/bin` but it shows command not found. The Python console opens when I give `#./python3.5`

I'm not sure what is going wrong but looks like I'm missing a small step here. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you tried `./python3`?  Usually the current working directory is **not** in `$PATH` (and that with good reasons).

Comment: P.S.: Why build 3.5 from source?  https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-python.html#InstallPython3FromLatest

Comment: link the opt binaries to /usr/local/bin for example: `ln -s /opt/python/python3 /usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: Gave the wrong directory in $PATH, my bad.. it worked.. thanks @tink